# Model Validation With MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm implementing MVC based website using the Razor engine.

I have created the validation to be in the model.
i.e. Student validation is like this:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Student.StudentMetaData))]
public partial class Student
{
       internal sealed class StudentMetaData
       {
              [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "FirstNameRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(StudentMessages))]
              public object FirstName { set; get; }

              [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "FatherNameRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(StudentMessages))]
              public object FatherName { set; get; }
       }
}
```

The student already implements the IDataErrorInfo interface. The data fields exist in the other partial class (the partial class created by T4 file).

The problem is when I use it with client validation in `Razor` view using:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FatherName, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FatherName)
```

it doesn't get the messages I specified in my resource files.

I have tried the same technique before with WPF and it works just fine.

I allowed the client validation in the Web.config and used this in my view:

```
@{
    HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: `object` is not an appropriate type for `FirstName` or `FatherName`.  Use `string`.

Comment: And your class would probably need to be `public` not `internal`, but you will find this far easier if you use view models and apply the validation attributes to the view model properties

Comment: I Really apologize for the inconvenience. and thanks for the fast responses.the problem with that my Partial Classes with in different name space.

Comment: P.s. Both the Internal state and object type is correct.

Comment: @WalidAshraf, I would delete the question. This will not help anybody.

Comment: @ataravati, You should vote to close it :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I didn't know there was an option for that under "off-topic".

Answer (score 0):

```
Add Name space in modal class in mvc.
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

 public class TelePhones
    {      
        [Required (ErrorMessage  = "MobileNo is required")]
        public long MobileNo { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        [Range(15, 70, ErrorMessage = "Price must be between 15 and 70")]
        public int Age { get; set; }
}
client side validation in mvc

 <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MobileNo)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MobileNo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MobileNo)
        </div> 
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)       
       </div> 
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age)
        </div>
```